# pushing to Heroku gives error "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been at this for an hour or two, but can't seem to figure out what the problem may be.

I was using sqlite3 for dev but before pushing to heroku I decided to switch to pg (using ubuntu), and it works fine on my local dev environment.

then I pushed to Heroku I keep getting a blank bage with the follow:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

'this doesn't really help. **Is there a log file for production I can access via heroku?**

Also my best guess is it has something to do with the bd, maybe it didn't load properly. I checked my heroku account and click the following addon:

Heroku Postgres Dev :: Olive

now my db says size of 6mb but tables 0, which is concerning. **However I don't know how to query my db on heroku and there seems to be no interface on the site to view my db. Does db not automatically push with "git push heroku master"**

Anyways, db is my best guess at the moment but I can't be certain, I'm not sure what to do since I have no logs

EDIT:

I was able to check the db on heroku using:

```
heroku pg:psql
```

from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql
however, there are no enteries in my db, there are enteries in my dev db but apparently it did not transfer to heroku, is there a way to push (or overwrite) your heroku db with the one in your dev environment?

**Kyle:**
I tried the taps thing,Failed to connect to database:

```
  Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError -> PG::Error: FATAL:  password authentication fai
led for user "pc"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pc" however I get the error:
```

pc us my username for pg on my ubuntu machine, however my password is ok since its working on my local machine

my database.yml file

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: someapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: pc
  password: ***

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: someapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: pc
  password: ***

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: someapp_development
  pool: 5
```

EDIT: I checked the log and it is infact the db causing the problem, the enteries in my table aren't being pushed into heroku and with an empty db my app is crashing (bad design I know)

Comment: check your logs with `heroku logs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to migrate your production database

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku restart
```

If you need the data imported to your heroku db, see [**this**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps#import-push-to-heroku)

```
 gem install taps   
 heroku db:push
```

**edit:**
try this alternative method:

```
heroku db:push postgres://user:pass@localhost/dbname
```

Comment: 0 rows or 0 tables? Are your tables there?

Comment: when I go through the heroku dashboard, it says under statistics for pg Tables: 0 but when I access my db through the console I can see all my db, but when I query them select * from x; I get the correct schema but rows = 0

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the user postgres has no DB password set on Ubuntu by default. That means, that you can login only to that account when you use the postgres OS user account.

Assuming, that you have root access on the box you can do:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

If that fails with `database "postgres" does not exists error,` then you are most likely not on a Ubunutu or Debian server :-) In this case simply add `template1` to the command:

```
sudo -u postgres psql template1
```

The any of those commands fail with an error `psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "pc"` then check the file `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf:` There must be a line like this as the first non-comment line:

```
local   all         postgres                          ident
```

For newer versions of PostgreSQL `ident` actually might be `peer`. That's OK also.

Inside the `psql` shell you can give the **DB** user `postgres` a password:

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'newPassword';
```

Now you should be able to give pgAdmin a valid password for the DB superuser and it will be happy too. :-)